# Prevent window.location.href from encoding url

Tags: javascript, html

I want to redirect the user to the url "/some/link+with+garbage/". When I use `window.location.href="/some/link+with+garbage/"`

I'm redirected to "/some/link%2Bwith%2Bgarbage/" which fails.

Is there a way to prevent `window.location.href` from encoding the url?

Comment: How are you doing this? With a button or what?

Comment: Yeah, you can think of it like a button. I'm using the ddslick library for jquery: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: No problems for me with the code you provided. It may be something to do with how it is interacting with ddslick library? Can you provide more code, info, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has to do with ddslick library. In the console, if I type `document.location.href="/some+thing/summary"`, I'm sent to the page "/some%2Bthing/summary". Anyway around this?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this issue, the problem is not with the encoding of the url but another problem in my code. I tried to read from the url after page load and failed to properly decode the url using `decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)`.

Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help.